# clown trying to clean up a string with RegEx

Tags: regex, autohotkey

I'm trying to parse through an mht (text) file and extract just certain lines.
RegExMatch is working just fine to do that.
However, inside my loop, I want to strip away EVERYTHING from those particular lines except the 7 digit string which consists of the letter "E" followed by 6 digits.

Here is my latest failed attempt.
This clown clearly doesn't know much RegEx.

Help?

Thanks

```
If RegExmatch(A_LoopReadLine,"E\d\d\d\d\d\d")
    {
    ECode := RegExReplace(A_LoopReadLine, "^[Ed\d\d\d\d\d\d]", "")
    FileAppend, %ECode%., G:\2013.txt
    }
```

Comment: `7` or `6` digits?and which language is this?you need to specify the language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
 RegExReplace(A_LoopReadLine, "^.*(E\d{6}).*$", "$1")
```

`\d{6}` represents 6 digits..`{}` is a quantifier..so `{n}` means match preceding character n times

`()` represents a group..so everything which is captured within the group can be referenced through `$n` where n is the group no.

Comment: Yes sir. That produced a clean list. And I learned some Regex too. Thanks!